# Setting field using reflect.Set

Tags: reflection, go

I have code

```
var t reflect.Type = LaunchController(route.controller)

    // create controller ptr .
    var appControllerPtr reflect.Value = reflect.New(t)
    fmt.Println(appControllerPtr) //#=> <**controller.AppController Value>
    var appController reflect.Value = appControllerPtr.Elem()
    // Create and configure base controller
    var c *Controller = &Controller{
            Request: r,
            Writer: w,
            Name: t.Name(),
        }

    //this should assign *goninja.Controller field in application controllers
    var controllerField reflect.Value = reflect.ValueOf(appController).Field(0)
    controllerField.Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(c))
```

This creates pointer to element, and afterwards trying to assign value, into 0 field of this struct.

My struct, that i'm trying to reflect looks like

```
type AppController struct {
  *goninja.Controller
}
```

However when I'm trying to assign this field with code

```
controllerField.Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(c))
```

I'm facing following error

```
reflect: reflect.Value.Set using value obtained using unexported field
```

What am i doin wrong? Also I cant understand why my `reflect.New(t)` returns `reflect.Value` with 2 asterisks in beginning `**`

Answer (score 2):

You don't give your complete code, so I have to guess a bit, but I suspect that the `Controller` field of the `AppController` structure has a lower-case name.  Right?  Here is my attempt to produce a minimal example from your code: [working](http://play.golang.org/p/zmjNP5HWsi) (with upper-case field name) and [non-working](http://play.golang.org/p/x_rYrw530R) (with lower-case fieldname).

Also: where you write `reflect.ValueOf(appController).Field(0)`, the `appController` is already of type `reflect.Value`, so the `ValueOf` is not required.  You can just write `appController.Field(0)` as in the example code I linked above.

Comment: Controller field of my struct AppController is just embedded field. I've checked if I have any unexporting fields, and none avaialble. Also reason why am i doing 2 times ValueOf - because otherwise i have error
`reflect: call of reflect.Value.FieldByName on ptr Value`.
Updated code with comment

Comment: Can you provide complete code (*e.g.* on play.golang.org) which shows the error message(s)?

Comment: Not sure how can i do that, since i have few different modules